# Understand WPF Binding CommandParameter="{Binding}"

Tags: wpf, binding

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I can't find the answer: in the following xaml what does `CommandParameter` binding to? Or in general, what does `"{Binding}"` mean?

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=List}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`{Binding ...}` is a MarkupExtension.
In its usual form it takes a Path like `{Binding Path=someProperty, ...}` (or its short form `{Binding someProperty, ...}`).
So the path in `{Binding}` is empty which means the Binding is bound to whatever Source there is for the Binding. This might be a little easier to understand if you know, that `{Binding}` is actually the same as `{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`.

So in your case CommandParameter gets the value of the current DataContext of the Button.

Answer (score 16):

An Empty `{Binding}` will pass the current DataContext of the control to the Executed and CanExecute methods respectively.