# How do I access the bound value of a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, event-handling

I have the following XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectButtonColumnDataTemplate">
        <Button Content="Select" Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand}" Click="SelectButtonClick" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<ListView x:Name="listFeedSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="542.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchCollection}">
    <ListView.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>                
            <RotateTransform/>                
            <TranslateTransform/>            
            </TransformGroup>        
            </ListView.RenderTransform>        
    <ListView.View>            
        <GridView>                
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Feed Name" x:Name="listFeedSearchName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedName}"  />                
            <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Feed Address" x:Name="listFeedSearchAddress" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedUrl}" />                
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header=" " CellTemplate="{StaticResource SelectButtonColumnDataTemplate}" />            
        </GridView>        
        </ListView.View>    
</ListView>     
</Grid>
```

Add the following Event Handler:

```
private void SelectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What I would like to do is output that rows individual binded value.

How would I do this, I know it's something along the lines of:

```
var data = (sender as Button)...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the button CommandParameter to (thanks Bolu):

```
"{Binding}"
```

then the following code will retrieve the current clicked object and display a messagebox. where foo is the class used to populate the gridview

```
 public class foo
 {
    string FeedName {get;set;}
    string FeedUrl {get;set;}
 }

 public void InitialiseListView(List<Foo> Items)
 {
    listFeedSearch.ItemsSource = Items;
 }

 private void SelectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    foo b = (foo)(sender as Button).CommandParameter;

    string s = string.format("Name: {0} URL: {1}",b.FeedName,b.FeedUrl);
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: foo is the name of the class where the data came from e.g. i had a class.

In the case of my example the list's itemsource was set to ' List<foo> ' I'll edit my post to show that better

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use `{Binding}`  :[Xaml: Binding to the current DataContext](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/08/26/xaml-binding-to-the-current-datacontext.aspx)

Ref: [Understand WPF Binding CommandParameter="{Binding}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377690/help-understand-wpf-binding-commandparameter-binding/5378269#5378269)