# how to pass generic list in CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have command which I am executing from my XAML (view) using below code:

```
<HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkGoToCommand,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="ABCD">
  <TextBlock Text="ABCD" TextDecorations="Underline"/></HyperlinkButton>
```

Presently `CommandParameter` pass as string and it’s working fine but I want to pass `CommandParameter` as `List` (single item generic list) rather than as string.

Comment: if your command and your generic list is within the same viewmodel you did not need a commandparameter at all. so pls give some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind collection from (XAML) control for an example from combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:name="combobox" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
<HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkGoToCommand}", CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=combobox, Path=ItemsSource}"></HyperlinkButton>
```

If you want to bind collection from ViewModel:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.YourCollectionPropertyFromViewModel}" or
CommandParameter="{Binding YourCollectionFromViewModel}"
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377690/help-understand-wpf-binding-commandparameter-binding) for more detail explanations.

Regards,