# Getting a control's information

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, windows-phone-8

My project is utilizing MVVM with C#. I've bounded my button command to a RelayCommand, and I wish to get information about my button. I wish to get this information so that I can use it in my RelayCommand. Unfortunately I do not know how to send this information to my RelayCommand, nor do I know which EventArgs I need to receive in my RelayCommand to get this Information.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Decoration}" x:Name="MyLB">         
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddGearCommand, ElementName=MyLB}" >
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">

                                <View:ShielGear/>
                         </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="HEJ MED DIG LUDER" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The ShielGear contains a Path element which the button takes it shape after. The RelayCommand I've bounded the command to is:

```
 AddGearCommand = new RelayCommand<T>(addGear);


    private void addGear(T e)
    {

    }
```

Furthermore is it possible to parse more than one Type to the relaycommand?
I am also unsure if I should use Commandparameters?

Comment: what information about your button you want in your handler?

Comment: You can use the button's [CommandParameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377690/help-understand-wpf-binding-commandparameter-binding) to send data to your command

Comment: @nit I would like to get the information from the view:ShielGear or the index of the button in the list.

Comment: @Omribitan If I use the CommandParameter and only use binding, like the way referred to, what kind of Type do I need in my RelayCommand to get this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing the button (a UI element) from the ViewModel.  This is breaking the separation of concerns and will make life difficult for you later if you need to refactor the UI.

Instead, add a value to the buttons binding which will pass the data you need into the command.  Often, this will be the object that is bound to your listboxitem.

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddGearCommand, ElementName=MyLB}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Then you need to modify your RelayCommand to be typed with the actual type of your data element.

```
public RelayCommand<myDataType> AddGearCommand { get;set;}
```

Comment: Okay so How would I bind the lists selectedIndex in commandparameter?

Comment: You don't need to.  The XAML already "knows" about which item it is bound to, so passing back it's binding reference should be enough

Comment: Okay so I have written the same XAML code. But what should I do in the MyDataType? I am most interested in getting the selectedIndex from the list. Because I need it for another list comparison.

Comment: The data type will be whatever the type is that you are binding to.  What type is your `Decoration` object.  If it is an ObservableCollection<x> then your datatype is `x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a name to your `ListBox` you can use `CommandParameter` to send the `SelectedIndex` as a parameter

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ...>
```

In your command

```
<Button BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddGearCommand, ElementName=MyLB}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedIndex}">
```

Then, your `RelayCommand` decleration will be as follows:

```
public RelayCommand<int> AddGearCommand { get; set; }
```

And in your command :

```
AddGearCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(selectedIndex =>
{
     // do whatever you want
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get a ton of information from the button, however non of it is relevant. So is there any way to get the selectedIndex of the button I chose from the List?

Comment: @JonasN89 the `SelectedIndex` is information you need to retreive from the `ListBox`, not the `Button`. I update my answer accordingly but note that simply clicking the button will not make it the `SelectedItem` of your `ListBox`, since the `UIElement` catching the mouse click is the `Button` and not the `ListBox`. if this is the case you'll need something different

Answer (score 0):

Pass your button name in Commandparameter and in viewmodel cast your parameter as button.
now you can get all info of your button.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnPrint"  MinWidth="70" Margin="5"  Content="Print" 
                            Command="{Binding Print}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnPrint}" ></Button>
```

ViewModel:

private RelayCommand _commandPrint;

```
    public ICommand Print
    {
        get { return _commandPrint ?? (_commandPrint = new RelayCommand(param => this.PrintGrid(param), Canprint)); }
    }
```

private void PrintGrid(object param)

```
    {

        var btn = param as Button;

    }
```

Comment: So I added an Name to my button and the command parameter part to. 
x:Name="ButtonListOfGear",CommandParameter="{Binding ButtonListOfGear}". 

And in the ViewModel I gave the RelayCommand of type Button, but when I run the code and put an break point the Button is set to null.

   AddGearCommand = new RelayCommand<Button>(addGear);
        

        private void addGear(Button e)
        {
         
        }